# Need assistance in .java code which is pushed to bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, github, jenkins, bitbucket

I have made changes in one of the .java code through eclipse and push it to the bitbucket but even after that the error is showing , how do i confirm that my changes are there reflected or not on bitbucket?

Comment: You can access Bitbucket directly via a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

> the error is showing

It should be an error showing *locally*

Beside accessing Bitbucket directly on a web browser, you can also check if the error persists by cloning the repository in a new empty folder (*outside* your current local repository folder), and import it in Eclipse for testing.

Comment: I have locally cloned it and made the changes , pushed it to bitbucket bht note sure whether current environment is using that .java code or not

Comment: @user19589616 Can you clone it back, again, and see if the .java code matches what you expect?